# Redux data comes too late into the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

React-redux data comes too late, i need the props.user in the component did mount method

```
class GroupsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groups: [],
    }
  }

  async fetchGroups (){
    fetchGroupsFirebase().then((res) => {this.setState({groups:res})})
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchGroups();
    
  }
  
  render(){}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  user: selectCurrentUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupsPage);
```

I need the user from mapStateToProps in the component did mount method, but it is null at that point, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronising the `componentDidMount` method with state and props update in the correct order will depend on what actions you were calling in to set the state in the Redux store, but you can try the `componentDidUpdate` method to make sure the states locally are updated when the props are updated.